# How to make a contact default dialer for phone app iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios4

How we can add a number in iphone address book programmatically and make it default contacts number for the person .If person having more then one contacts in the addressbook then by what way we can make this number his default dialer .When ever i tap on his name only the number i assign it should be call.Is that possible by ios 4.3 .

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iphone's phone application does not directly dial a default number. Even if a person has only one number saved against him/her, first the contact details are opened and then any number can be dialed. Since the app opens up details in any case and deos not support setting default, the sdk doesnt support programmatically setting default.

Comment: i Thinks so but what i got if you have any 4-5 number for a person in the addresbook the number that is on top in labels becomes the default one for that person when you tab on his name the first number is called always .Any way thanks Bush for confirming .Do we have any way by which we can put our added contact number to put it in the top among all the labels in the iphone addresbook?

Comment: thats what im telling you, the number on the top is not default and is not dialed automatically. So there is no point in putting a number on the top. Even if i have 4 numbers for a contact, tapping on the name will open the contact details and allow me to tap on a contact. There is no concept of default number here. try using the iPhone Phone app.